# how to pull multiple files html5 jquery

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

How to pull multiple files using FileSystem Api (Html5) and send to javascript as an array.
Actually I'm trying to select multiple files and add them to my slideshow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
--A.J

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `multiple` attribute to your input

```
 <input type="file" multiple />
```

You can also add `webkitdirectory`, `directory`, and/or `mozdirectory` to specify you want to allow users to upload entire folders. These are not standard, obviously (although plain ol' `directory` is/may be)

Then in your JavaScript, your input element will have a `files` array containing meta info on the selected files, ripe for using in the FileReader API. For example:

```
 <input type="file" multiple onchange="doSomethingWithThese(this.files)" />
```

(I don't recommend the inline JavaScript, just for example)

Comment: Thanks Matt Let me try this I'll post the comment back.

Comment: What I need now is the file path which i can add as array to the slideshow.

Comment: You can't get the file path. But you can use the FileReader API to get a data url, then use the data url as the src of an image in your slide show.

Comment: I've tried that but no joy, is there any possibility u could post any example here so that i can get the point.

Comment: I've tried doing it here but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.
http://jsfiddle.net/j_cart007/QvXpt/
Could you please have a look at it and let me know what am I doing wrong. Thanks

--A.J

Comment: I can't find any evidence that "mozdirectory" works for Firefox. Chrome seems to be the only browser that currently supports this.