# Folder upload for browers other than chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, folderbrowserdialog, input-type-file

I want to support folder upload option.

**input type="file" name="files[]" multiple directory webkitdirectory mozdirectory**

This works in chrome and opera and not elsewhere. I know its not supported by FF. But is there a way to do so. I came across the zipping option here([Select directory for HTML5 multiple file input in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518335/select-directory-for-html5-multiple-file-input-in-firefox)) as well but I dont want it that way. Can someone suggest a way to start off with this, so that I can support/simulate folder upload in FF/IE.

Comment: [Answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518335/select-directory-for-html5-multiple-file-input-in-firefox)

Comment: Please see my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33431704/195216
It shows folder uploading via drag'n'drop and via dialog in chrome and firefox!

Answer (score 1):

Folder upload is now supported by Firefox (as of version 50, released on 15 November 2016). The developer notes are here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/50

Folder upload it already supported by Microsoft Edge browser (the replacement for Internet Explorer). It is documented, with PI calls, here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/html5/folder-upload/

As Chrome and Opera have already supported folder upload for a long time, the last remaining major browser that does not support folder upload is Safari.